# Elastic search conversion php

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I'm currently working on migrating a MySQL query to Elasticsearch in PHP. The original MySQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT id,username,full_name 
FROM users 
WHERE id<>4 AND (username LIKE %john% OR full_name LIKE %full_name%) 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Now, I need assistance in translating this MySQL query to Elasticsearch using PHP. I'm specifically looking for guidance on how to construct the Elasticsearch query to achieve the same filtering and pagination functionality.

Any help or examples demonstrating how to accomplish this in Elasticsearch with PHP would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It'd be something like this:

```
GET /users/_search?pretty=true
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "username": "john"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "full_name": "full_name"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": "4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```